what's the name of 2 controller into 1 usb converter circuit
i had 2 game generic controller for Pc, and both of them were connected to this exact circuits and output was one USB. for my curiosity i disconnected this pcb circuit and removed the parts. but I'm stuck because i want to rebuild it for myself , but components are so odd . and there was something under the epoxy Wich i couldn't recover when removing the resin. so under the epoxy is a total mystery for me. can anyone help me please solve this problem, or does anybody know how gamepad pinout works? my gamepads have 8 pinout and i can't figure out how to make them into 4pin usb. 



https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chip_on_board

@AlirezaAbz, I might be wrong, but I think you want what has been done many times already. Create a game controller from scratch from switches and some processor. @ me if this is what you want & I'll post an answer aligned more to this. But will wait as such an answer does not directly address your question.

What is/was under the epoxy blob is/was either an ASIC or microcontroller.
It cannot be known what it was, and it was the bridge between the USB interface and the game controller buttons, and by the looks of it, the buttons were connected via a serial shift register to have less wires to the set of buttons.
The IC inside the epoxy blob looks like the original host for the controlles and it shows them as standard HID devices on USB to the PC.
You can do the same with any MCU that implements USB.
Back in the day when common cheap MCUs did not implement USB hardware, people used clever programming tricks to implement USB in software.
There is no need to replicate an unknown circuit. Get some modern microcontroller with built-in USB. Make it a USB joystick and attach some buttons it can read.

is there any chance you could help me with the exact ic models or circuits? I'll be very thankful if you could help me. i just need a picture of circuit so i can rebuild it.

Buy any modern MCU dev board with USB. It does not matter which is it as long as you can program it to be a USB HID joystick. Asking for any specific thing to buy is off-topic.

@st2000 No, it's not what I want. I am not the original poster.

@AlirezaAbz Many sets of instructions on making USB game controllers on Google, but here is a game controller library with a list of supported Arduino boards:  https://github.com/MHeironimus/ArduinoJoystickLibrary/wiki/Supported-Boards
